# custom styling with(out) execCommand (how to deal with overlapping tags)

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

Because execCommand doesn't work as expected I want to build a similar function on my own. It should be possible to apply different styles to a text. If I want to add a style it is easy as I can simply use range.surroundContents which let me put for example a span-tag around the selection. I also can remove tags by removing parent nodes from the current cursor position. The only think I can't find a solution to is how to handle the following cases with overlapping tags:

Case A:

```
<span class="bold">This is some text</span> that goes on <span class="italic">and on until the end</span>
```

Imagine User selects the text from some to until and applies a underline. The change should be like:

```
<span class="bold">This is <span class="unterline">some text</span></span><span class="underline"> that goes on </span><span class="italic"><span class="underline">and on until</span> the end</span>
```

Case B:

```
<span class="bold">This is some text</span> that goes on <span class="italic">and on until the end</span>
```

Imagine User selects the text from some to until and applies a bold. The change should be like:

```
<span class="bold">This is some text that goes on </span><span class="italic"><span class="bold">and on until</span> the end</span> ... or similar valid output.
```

Case C:

```
<span class="color-orange">This is some text</span> that goes on <span class="color-blue">and on until the end</span>
```

Imagine User selects the text from some to until and applies a yellow color. The change should be like:

```
<span class="color-orange">This is </span><span class="color-yellow">some text that goes on and on until</span><span class="color-blue"> the end</span>
```

How can I achieve that?
As it seems like a common problem I'm pretty sure that someone already figured this out but I couldn't find anything yet. Hopefully someone around SO can at least point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: I am looking for the exact same thing. I was looking at rangy's CSSApplier class which handles those cases but allows applying css classes only and no inline styles :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: it's hard to do this sensibly and reliably for the general case. I started work on a Rangy module for this, got bogged down and abandoned it.

Take a look at the [draft HTML Editing specification](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html) Aryeh Gregor of Google worked on a couple of years ago. He also wrote an unoptimized [JavaScript implementation](https://github.com/ayg/editing/blob/master/implementation.js) of the algorithms in his spec targeted at the latest browsers of the time.